# Meteor - Preloading assets (not CSS and JS)

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router, preload

I was wondering if any of you have any experience with preloading content in Meteor. I found the following package but it looks like it's strictly for loading JS and CSS assets:

https://github.com/MiroHibler/meteor-preloader

Assuming there will be quite a few heavy images and video, what would be a smart way to approach this? And would there be a way to implement this within iron-router itself?

Thanks.

Comment: I will try with http://www.createjs.com/#!/PreloadJS : )